# ! is not a member of String

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to upgrade my sbt version from 0.12.3 to 0.13.0 but after it's trying to load a project I get following error:

```
! is not a member of String
```

Error occurs in line where I execute external command:

```
 ("tar cf " + (buildRoot / "SOURCES").toString + "/" + ver + ".tar -C " + buildRoot.toString + " dir").!
```

In previous version all was fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what has changed in the newest version?

Edit: Problem resolved. It's needed to add:

```
 import sbt.Process._
```

in object where are you trying to use postfixOps for example:

```
  val success:Int = ((dir / "script.sh" toString) !)
```

Comment: Is there `import scala.sys.process._` before `("tar cf " + ...).!` in your code?

Comment: As a matter of style, rather than using implicits to write `myString.!`, I prefer to explicitly write `Process(myString).!`. It's a matter of taste, I suppose, but I think being explicit is kinder to the person reading my build.

Answer (score 6):

The ! command (for processes) either comes from [sbt's process API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Process.html) or from Scala's.

If you're planning to use sbt's logging  with forking (HIGHLY recommend), then you want to make sure you `import sbt.Process._`

Also, you proabbly want to have your code look more like:

```
val logger: sbt.Logger = ???  //(usually streams.value.log)
val success:Int = (dir / "script.sh" toString) ! logger
```

Comment: You're absolutely right but before I added `import sbt.Process._`    ! command didn't work, even if i had `import scala.sys.process._`

Comment: how about "import sbt._" or something from 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Console-Project.html ?